# Is it possible to rollback a changeset using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi?

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc

Following code try to rollback a changeset using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi. But "*The specified change type Rollback is not supported*." is raised when calling CreateChangesetAsync. Is this a limitation of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi? Or I did something wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;

namespace RestRollBackInTFS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const String collectionUri = @"https://myTfs.visualstudio.com/";
            VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(collectionUri),
                new VssClientCredentials()
            );
            TfvcHttpClient tfsClient = connection.GetClient<TfvcHttpClient>();
            int changeSetIdToRollBack = 11651;
            var changeSet = tfsClient.GetChangesetAsync(changeSetIdToRollBack, maxChangeCount: 10, includeDetails: true).Result;
            foreach (var c in changeSet.Changes)
            {
                c.ChangeType = VersionControlChangeType.Rollback;
            }
            TfvcChangeset newC = new TfvcChangeset();
            newC.Changes = new List<TfvcChange>(changeSet.Changes);
            var ret = tfsClient.CreateChangesetAsync(newC).Result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to open an issue on the Rest api GitHub repo.

Comment: Thanks. Is https://developer.github.com/v3/ the site you mentioned? I think that the issue is with Microsoft TeamFoundation. I am not sure how it is related to github Rest api?

Comment: No, I mean to Azure DevOps Api GitHub: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples

Comment: Opened an issue there. Not sure what I may expect.